# overall matching

Tags: regex

to search a single char in RegEx is easy.

exp: at least one digit:

```
\d
```

so i need to match at least 2 digit in the text

```
.*\d{2}.* or .*\d\d.* #### "d2dr5" -> not match... d22r or d00r match..
```

will not work because RegEx engine look for these numbers as consecutive how can I search for overall? for example

I want to match at least 3 digit and 2 uppercase word in the text. and the text length can be max 12. how can I do this ? If you can give an explained example so then i may have a point to re-search

example match:

a9r2lDpDf2 - matches. at least 3 digit 2 upper case and not exceeding 12 char in total.

Comment: please give more examples to illustrate the rules . Would the following be matched . A5T6at , AA666 , AA6666 , 6AAAAA6AA6 , $$&&EEE%%55

Comment: Are you trying to check the strength of a password? (Helps to answer questions if we know *why* you have the question.)

Comment: @amal your first not match because at least 3 digit required. all others matches.

@Richard these combinations often used to detect password strength but here i want to learn that how to do overall matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure there is only three digits in the string you can try this (add start and end of string if needed):

```
[^\d]*\d[^\d]*\d[^\d]*\d[^\d]*
```

`[^\d]*` - anything except digits.

Same pattern can be used to check for uppercase letters:

```
[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*
```

RegEx is not the best tool to check length. The language you use has something like `length(str)` or `str.length` or `str.length()` etc.

It can be done with lookahead feature. This is how RegEx looks in Perl (and it does what you ask):

```
/^(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z]).{12}$/
```

`(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d)` - "looks ahead" to see if there are 3 digits

`(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])` - "looks ahead" to see if there are 2 uppercase letters

`.{12}` - length must be precisely 12 characters. Any character 12 times.

Comment: I want to match at least 3 digit and 2 uppercase word in the text. and the text length can be max. 12

Comment: Hello tresh I think you didn't understand my question. I want to combine these requirements in one RegEx.

Comment: Using these two sequentially is much easier. Why do you have a limitation to use only one regex?

Comment: What flavor of regex uses `\u` to match uppercase letters?

Comment: @Alan I thought I've seen it somewhere. Maybe no one. I will remove it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think regexes are the optimal solution here , but for academic interest

```
(?=(.*[0-9]){3})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2}).{5,12}
```

Comment: (?=) is a zero width look ahead expression. Meaning that it will look ahead into the string for the indicated pattern, if it isnt there, then there will be no match.So the regex reads , any character occurring 5-12 times , and the string must contain 2 uppercase characters at any position (?=) and 3 digits at any position (?=) .